# StructError: At path: meta -- Expected an object, but received: null, getTransaction with GetVersionedTransactionConfig

Tags: web3.js, transactions, versionedtransactions

I am getting this error when I call the getTransaction api.
Is there any fix for this? Postman returns data but this api always return an error.

An example hash would be: "`2iyosYtJBwPUDxXSVJ5UnUXi3FuB3X2XaeUWk3WicpLXJuiRJiBjfNK46yeh1hZeHRuxdp8gFxh5TnVdHDiY1Dk7`"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this, you found a bug! https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/pull/1812 has the fix. In the meantime, you can call `getParsedTransaction` instead or hack your local web3.js to include the fix

Comment: Thank you!! Jon C